# Random effects in ZIP or ZINB models - count portion, Bernoulli portion, or both?

Tags: mixed-model, random-effects-model, glmm, zero-inflation, bugs

I'm building some zero-inflated models that need to include random effects, and I can't find a definitive answer for whether I should include the random effects in the part of the model that describes counts, the part that describes the probability that a zero is structural or not, or both.

Below is Ben Bolker et al.'s ZIP model for the owl example. He includes a random intercept in the portion of the model that determines owl counts, log(lamba[i]), and he does not include a random effect (or fixed effects) when modeling the Bernoilli probability for whether a zero is a true zero. Is this always the correct way to include random effects in a ZIP model? If not, when should random effects be included to model the Bernoulli probability?

Source: https://groups.nceas.ucsb.edu/non-linear-modeling/projects/owls/WRITEUP/owls.pdf

```
model {

#PRIORS
for (m in 1:5){
beta[m] ~ dnorm(0, 0.01) # Linear effects
}
alpha ~ dnorm(0, .01)
sigma ~ dunif(0, 5)
tau <- 1/(sigma*sigma)
psi ~ dunif(0, 1)
for(j in 1:nnests){
a[j] ~ dnorm(0, tau)
}

for(i in 1:N){
SibNeg[i] ~ dpois(mu[i])
mu[i] <- lambda[i]*z[i]+0.00001 ## hack required for Rjags -- otherwise 
'incompatible'
#Bernoulli model - no random effect
z[i] ~ dbern(psi)
#Count model - includes random effect
log(lambda[i]) <- offset[i] + alpha + inprod(X[i,],beta) + a[nest[i]]
}
```